# react redux store state from ajax calls

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

I have tried to look it up and found some ideas, mostly with: normalizr -> https://github.com/paularmstrong/normalizr

but I have this question:

I get my data from the ajax call should I create classes from it, like: User Object, Post Object

ie:

```
// data.json from backend:
{
    user: {
        id: 1,
        name: "dan",
        etc....
    },
    post: {
        id: 1,
        content: "lorem ipsum",
        etc....
    }
}
```

I could store it exactly like that, or I could create objects that will be easily used and then store in the state.

ie:

```
class User {
    constructor(data) {
        this.id = data.id;
        this.name = data.name;
    }

    getName() {
        return this.name;
    }
}
```

Bottom line should I simply get the json, and place inside the state.

OR

I would create objects from the json and then store it in the state, something like that:

```
let user = createUserFromJson(json); // User object returned

dispatch({type: ADD_USER, {user});
```

Comment: Can you clarify what you are asking exactly? You would store ajax response in the state like you have done in option 1 with Json. Not sure what you mean by the second example.

Comment: thanks @MartinMazzaDawson, update the question, second option is to create class objects from the json and the store the in the state

Comment: You don't want to store classes in the state because they are not serializable. I don't see the benefits of option two either, it's just more code

Comment: Isn't that better to have easy access to attributes? if the backend api changes that means I'll need to refactor all views on how I access my state. ie: user.getFirstName() VS user.name.fname

Comment: As @MartinMazzaDawson mentioned, you don't want to store objects that are not serializable (carry functions etc.). Regarding normalization, it probably depends on how "reliable" the API is, in terms of how often does it introduce breaking changes and how coupled it is to your app. If you feel it's not "safe" enough to use the response as-is, normalize the entities as they are fetched and store the normalized version in store.